# Sorting array of structs on multiple elements in c#

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I have an array of structures.  The structure of my structs is this:

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct TOCRRESULTSHEADER
    {
        public int StructId;
        public int XPixelsPerInch;
        public int YPixelsPerInch;
        public int NumItems;
        public float MeanConfidence;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct TOCRRESULTSITEM
    {
        public short StructId;
        public short OCRCha;
        public float Confidence;
        public short X;
        public short Y;
        public short Width;
        public short Height;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct TOCRRESULTS
    {
        public TOCRRESULTSHEADER Hdr;
        public TOCRRESULTSITEM[] Item;
    }
```

I am populating a structure of type TOCRRESULTS like this:

```
  TOCRRESULTS MyArray = GetOCRForImage(filename);
```

I am sorting the array by the Y values just fine using this:

```
 Array.Sort<TOCRRESULTSITEM>(MyArray.Item, (a,b) => a.Y.CompareTo(b.Y));
```

Is there a way to sort by Y and X without having to write my own sorting routine?

I tried using LINQ:

```
 var newarray = OCRLetterArray.Item.OrderBy(x => x.Y).ThenBy(x => x.X).ToArray();
```

but it never sorted my array.

I apologize for the drastic change from my original posting.  I was hoping I could get away with a simple example.

Comment: Your LINQ example, as written here, won't do anything _by design_.

Comment: Edited my answer, should work in your case.

Comment: Yes it did.  I marked it as the answer.  THanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most efficient would still be to use Array.Sort, avoiding the allocation of a new array:

```
    Array.Sort(MyArray.Item, (a, b) =>
    {
        var comparison = a.Y.CompareTo(b.Y);
        return comparison == 0 ? a.X.CompareTo(b.X) : comparison;
    });
```

This will sort by Y then by X. You can easily switch it around to sort by X then by Y if you wish.

Comment: This involves a custom sorting routine, which the question asks not to do.  The question doesn't ask about efficiency.

Comment: That's not a sorting routine, it's a comparison function exactly like the ones used in the OrderBy/ThenBy examples, only it uses both X and Y. The sorting routine used here is Array.Sort().

Comment: To be exact, OrderBy uses a projection function whereas Array.Sort uses a comparison function. Neither is a sort routine.

Answer (score 3):

You have to reassign it:

```
var orderedArray = MyArray.OrderBy(a => a.Y).ThenBy(a => a.X).ToArray();
```

Comment: Why call `ToList`?  There's nothing here that says a `List` would be better than an array.

Comment: This is not sorting my array at all.  I used the code exactly as above.

Comment: The actual code is code that I inherited and it signicantly more complex that my original question.  I am modifying my original question now...

Comment: @Richard No, LINQ doesn't do an in place sort. Instead it will return a new array with the given ordering.  If it's important to do an in place sort you could copy it back to the first array.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
MyArray = MyArray.OrderBy(a => a.Y).ToArray();
```

Calling `OrderBy` on the array returns a new collection of type `IEnumerable<MyStructure>`.  It *doesn't* modify the original array.  Once you have the new collection, you can call `ToArray` on it, and reassign it to the original variable.

Comment: How will this help me sort by X and Y?

Answer (score 1):

Your LINQ solution looks fine, are you sure you are using it correctly? In contrast to `Array.Sort`, it is *returns* the new `IEnumerable` instead of sorting in-place (as does `Array.Sort`), so you would have to use

```
MyArray = MyArray.OrderBy(a => a.Y).ThenBy(a => a.X).ToArray();
```

You would have to show more code if this does not solve the problem.

Comment: When I use this, I get a "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable<MyArray>' 'MyArray[]' error

Comment: @Richard this suggests that your "MyArray" identifier isn't just an array variable - what is it?

Comment: I just rewrote the entire original question to better show what I am working with.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, implement [IComparable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
public struct MyStructure: IComparable, IComparable<MyStructure>
 {
      public int X;
      public int Y;

    public int CompareTo(MyStructure other)
    {
        return Y.CompareTo(other.Y);
    }

    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        return CompareTo((MyStructure)obj);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Isn't this a sorting routine?  The question asks how to do it "without having to write my own sorting routine."

Comment: In this way you can call `Array.Sort<MyStructure>(MyArray)` without defining every time the comparison delegate `(a,b) => a.Y.CompareTo(b.Y)`

Comment: I understand that, but it's still a sorting routine.

Comment: I don't understand.. you need some kind of routine or algorithm to sort a custom object or structure

Comment: ...Or you can just tell the `OrderBy` method which property to sort by, which is not defining your own sorting routine, but utilizing an existing one.  That's all I'm saying.  I'm not trying to be an ass; I'm just pointing out that the goal is to not have to define our own sorting routine.  Your solution is totally fine, otherwise.

Comment: @Dan CompareTo() is not a sorting routine, it's a comparison function.

Comment: When I said "Sorting routine," i meant something like a Bubble Sort.